# White page is it includes www normal without

Tags: wordpress

My domain is jrummyapps.com. If I go into my General settings my settings are such,

WordPress Address (URL) http://jrummyapps.com
Site Address (URL)  http://jrummyapps.com

If I change them to include the www. then http://jrummyapps.com gives me a white screen and http://www.jrummyapps.com does work. I have already spoken with my hosting company who said the DNS settings were set up correctly and that it seems to be more of a wordpress issue. Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to make it so that it does not matter if the www is there or not it will load my site?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your wordpress settings to include the www? That is all you need to do and it should do the trick, I didn't quite understand if that's what you said you *already* tried.

Comment: Yes I have tried that, the issue is that when they are as such,

WordPress Address (URL) http://www.jrummyapps.com Site Address (URL) http://www.jrummyapps.com

Then jrummyapps.com does not load correctly. I am starting to think that is an issue with wordpress and I need to do some debugging but this is new to me still.